# Still get error 'Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution' after creating firebase index

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter and order data together by where and orderBy function .
I get this error 'Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution' then I created an index in firebase console and the problem still found .

[image: screenshot of firebase console]

Comment: What does your query look like?  Are you sure that's the correct index?

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').limit(20).orderBy('price', descending: true).where(filterCondition['key'],
          arrayContains: filterCondition['value']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was filtering data with array field and I left it's index "Ascending" in firebase console and it must be "Array" . It works .